# Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database: unrecognized token: "$"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I've developed a tiny C#/SQl application with VS2012 and i will regret it for the rest of my life, anyway, i finished debugging, everything worked fine, here comes the tragedy: no setup publishing tool. So I tried the one click way with the publishing options etc and I've included .NET 4 framework, but when i tested nothing worked and the installer is saying that framework is missing and other stuffs, so back to my lab I changed to VS2010 to benefit from the setup ability... and i did and for me the app worked too and the installation also worked and installed the app.

Now I need to install the app in another PC but it doesn't have my server so i switched to sqlite.

here where comes this error about unrecogizable token because i imported my database from a excel with sql import /export wizard and it automatically wrote the table name as "Archive$", i can not get bake to the xls file now and i dont know how to rename it inside the db file. here is my proble . thx for helping me .

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DgvFilterPopup;
using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace ExpertGeoMaster_v._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DialogResult res;

        public static string p = @"C:\Users\abdellaziz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExpertGeoMaster v.1\ExpertGeoMaster v.1\bin\Debug\database.db";


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=./database.db;Version=2;New=True;Compress=True;"))
            {
                this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
                    DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(@"Select * from Archive$", cn);
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    da.Fill(DT);
                    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: have you looked up ConnectionStrings with C# there is a site online that gives examples of how to do all connection strings for every type of database out there

Comment: yes but since it have detected the $ i think it have connected to the database and gained access to the table... not??

Comment: so you have a table named `Archive$` pretty poor naming convention if you ask me..

Comment: i quote my self for you : **here where comes this error about unrecogizable token because i imported my database from a excel with sql import /export wizard and it automatically wrote the table name as "Archive$", i can not get bake to the xls file now and i dont know how to rename it inside the db file. here is my proble . thx for helping me .**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special characters like `$` are not normally allowed in identifiers.

You can use them anyway if you [use quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

```
new SQLiteDataAdapter(@"Select * from \"Archive$\"", cn);
new SQLiteDataAdapter(@"Select * from [Archive$]", cn);
new SQLiteDataAdapter(@"Select * from `Archive$`", cn);
```

Comment: thx it changed at least to another output, i have this as error:
Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database: no such table: Archive$ à Finisar.SQLite.sqlite2.Throw(Int32 sqliteResult, IntPtr pSQLiteErrMsg) à Finisar.SQLite.sqlite2.CheckOK(Int32 sqliteResult, IntPtr pSQLiteErrMsg) à Finisar.SQLite.sqlite2.compile(String zSql) à Finisar.SQLite.OneSQLStatement.Compile() à Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.ExecuteFirstStep() à Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.EnsureInitialization() à Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.get_FieldCount() à